# Loop inside a group to filter by comparng two column values

Tags: sql-server

```
   Col0 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
    --------------------
    1, 14, Orange, 10
    2, 14, Pineapple, 10
    3, 14, Pear, 14
    4, 19, Apple, 6
    5, 19, Banana, 5
```

In the table above, I want to return a row within each group in Col0 (i.e. 14 and 19) where the value in Col1 = Col3 and when there is no value in Col1 = Col3 within a group then return all rows

The result I expect is shown in the table below:

```
Col0 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
--------------------
1, 14, Pear, 14
2, 19, Apple, 6
3, 19, Banana, 5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your requirement doesn't seem to make sense, at least not to me. There are no records where `Col1=Col3` in your table. Perhaps you mean where `Col3` is the same for records that belong to the same group?

Comment: Any statement about SQL starting with `loop` is wrong until proven valid. Whatever you want to do, you don't need a loop for it

Comment: It looks like what you want is to bundle rows by their `Col1` value and filter out completely duplicates on the `Col3` values within that group.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thanks for your reply, in the original table Col1 = Col3 in row 3

Answer (score 1):

This works, not elegant though

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Col0 INT IDENTITY, Col1 INT, Col2 NVARCHAR(15), Col3 INT)
INSERT INTO @t
(Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT 14, 'Orange', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'Pineapple', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'Pear', 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 19, 'Apple', 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 19, 'Banana', 5

;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT
          T.Col1
        , Col2 = MAX(T.Col2)
        , Col3 = MAX(T.Col3)
    FROM @t T
    WHERE
        T.Col1 = T.Col3
    GROUP BY
        T.Col1
)
SELECT
      Col0 = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    , Z.Col1
    , Z.Col2
    , Z.Col3
FROM
(
    SELECT 
          X.Col1
        , X.Col2
        , X.Col3
    FROM cteX X
    UNION
    SELECT
          T.Col1
        , T.Col2
        , T.Col3
    FROM @t T
    WHERE
        T.Col1 <> T.Col3
    AND Col1 NOT IN (SELECT Y.Col1 FROM cteX Y)
) Z
```

output

```
Col0 | Col1 | Col2 | Col3
--------------------
1, 14, Pear, 14
2, 19, Apple, 6
3, 19, Banana, 5
```